# how to make these testcases code nice?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, refactoring, tdd

I am a freshman of TDD and C++, I write some code works but it seems ugly...

could you give me some tips on how to refactor these code?

I define testcases like this:

```
// define some test case
namespace test_case_planes {
const std::string t_filename = "planes.segy_first_trace";
boost::uintmax_t t_file_size = 5888;
boost::uintmax_t t_traces_size = 1;
boost::int16_t t_trace_samples_size = 512;
boost::int16_t t_sample_interval = 4000; // 2000us, 2ms
}

namespace test_case_ld0042_file_00018 {
const std::string t_filename = "ld0042_file_00018.sgy_first_trace";
boost::uintmax_t t_file_size = 12040;
boost::uintmax_t t_traces_size = 1;
boost::int16_t t_trace_samples_size = 2050;
boost::int16_t t_sample_interval = 2000; // 2000us, 2ms
}
```

and test like this(with google test)

```
TEST(Segy, constructWithNoParas){
    using namespace test_case_planes;
    segy::Segy* test_segy = new segy::Segy();
    EXPECT_EQ(test_segy->getFilename(), t_filename);
}

TEST(Segy, constructWithFilename){
    using namespace test_case_ld0042_file_00018;
    segy::Segy* test_segy = new segy::Segy(t_filename);
    EXPECT_EQ(test_segy->getFilename(), t_filename);
}

TEST(Segy, setFilename){
    using namespace test_case_ld0042_file_00018;
    segy::Segy* test_segy = new segy::Segy();
    test_segy->setFilename(t_filename);
    EXPECT_EQ(test_segy->getFilename(), t_filename);
}
```

Comment: "Seems Ugly" seems a little bit of a vague problem. What were you hoping for?

Comment: These tests actually look good to me.  If you are referring to some repeated code, it is acceptable in the context of unit testing, as long as the test's intentions are clear.  I'll refer you to the Pylons/Pyramid testing guidelines which apply to unit testing in general:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/community/testing.html

Comment: @Cagez Code duplication ist not acceptable. Not in productive code, nor in test code. Never. Test code has to be as clean and maintainable as productive code. Otherwise changes in productive code become expensive just because of that stupid unit tests...”let's stop tdd, its too much work”. So, how to refactor test code is a good question.

Comment: @hansmaad I disagree.  Yes, not repeating code is one of the most important programming virtues, but this is an exception.  Clear unit test intentions take priority over DRY for both readability and maintainability. I'm not saying abandon DRY completely, rather don't compromise clear test intentions for the sake of being clever, as the article states.

Comment: @Cagez thanks for your guidelines link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a fixture. I am not familiar with google test, but test fixtures should be available in most test frameworks. You should look into the documentation for that.